# RHEL setting a user specific max number of open files

Tags: rhel, limit, open-files, ulimit

I've set up below values in /etc/security/limits.conf in my RHEL machine.

```
* hard nofile 65535

@student hard nofile 100000
```

Is this the correct approach when setting a user specific max number of open files?

Should the `* hard nofile` value be always greater than the sum of user specific nofile values?

Answer (score 1):

> Should the * hard nofile value be always greater than the sum of user specific nofile values?

It does not need to be. 
The limits.conf(5) and limits(2) are also used for allowing some users to use 
more resource than default users.

Your limit entry will limits for default user(*) to open 65535 files, and for a user in the group **student** to open 100000.